# Making Drupal 7 show a menu link regardless of user authentication

Tags: drupal, menu, footer

To all the Drupal geniuses out there: I have a page that is viewable only by authenticated users but I want the link to the page to show up on the public footer menu. Right now Drupal hides the menu link unless the user is logged in.  I want it there whether the user is authenticated or not so if they aren't logged in, it takes them to the login page. No matter what I do, Drupal keeps hiding the menu link.  How can I override it?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, you can set the user roles that can view a specific block in the Blocks section. Then, i assume that if your menu is in the footer, you assigned that menu to the Footer block in the Blocks section. So, you only have to "Configure" the Footer block and set which user roles do you want that can view this menu int he "Visibility Options" section. By default, all of the options are unchecked, which means that the block is visible for all of the users. Notice that if there is more content in the Footer sections and you don't want that content visible for all of the users, then you have to create a new block, only for the menu.

Any other question, i'll be happy to help you. Regards.

Comment: Awesome.  I was hoping for a way to override a single menu item but creating a new block sounds like the most logical solution. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Just tried it and Drupal continues to hide the link unless the user is logged in. All the user roles under the visibility settings for the footer block are checked, cached cleared, and Drupal still hides that menu option.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Mmmm, i think it might be a permissions problem. Did you check if the "unregistered user role" has the necessary permissions to see that menu?

Comment: They can see that menu. Drupal is just hiding that menu item because unregistered users don't have permissions to that page. No matter how I try and trick Drupal, it knows the permissions so it won't show that menu item link in the footer unless they're logged in. I want them to see the link even though if they click on it it will take them to the login screen since they don't have access.

Comment: Then, you mean that unregistered users wouldn't see the link because they don't have permissions to that page? And now a question, how do you access to that page? If in your site, the user access to that page from a Main Menu o Navigaton link, then you can use the module Menu_Per_Role http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role. With this module you can set the visibility of a specific link in these menus. So, you can hide the access to the page and give visibility permissions of the page to unregistered users.

Comment: The other option is organize all of the content that you have in that page in blocks and do the same that i proposed to you with the Footer block. The you give visibility permissions to the page but you hide the blocks that you want in that section. Of course, you don't hide the link.